# dconf-editor, Where has apps>indicators>sound gone

Tags: 12.04

sound is no longer listed in my dconf-editor under apps>indicators>

Anyone know where to find it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: was going to remove rhythm box from volume/sound menu

Answer (score 0):

```
dconf-editor com/canonical/indicator/sound
```